# How to find an aliasing-free data structure

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am fighting the final boss of Rust, the borrow checker. This is a simplified version of a `mio` reactive network application I am working on. I spent too much time finding the right data structure for the task on hand. I want to register a connection while iterating over listening sockets that are able to accept new connections.

See the following code, or check it on the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Acollections%3A%3AHashMap%3B%0A%0Atrait%20ThingSet%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20register(%26mut%20self%2C%20thing%3A%20Box%3CThing%3E)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atrait%20Thing%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20act(%26mut%20self%2C%20reg%3A%20%26mut%20ThingSet)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Stream%3B%0A%0Aimpl%20Thing%20for%20Stream%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20act(%26mut%20self%2C%20reg%3A%20%26mut%20ThingSet)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Listener%3B%0A%0Aimpl%20Thing%20for%20Listener%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20act(%26mut%20self%2C%20reg%3A%20%26mut%20ThingSet)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20true%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20stream%20%3D%20Stream%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reg.register(Box%3A%3Anew(stream))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Loop%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20next%3A%20usize%2C%0A%20%20%20%20things%3A%20HashMap%3Cusize%2C%20Box%3CThing%3E%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Loop%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20new()%20-%3E%20Loop%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Loop%20%7B%20next%3A%201%2C%20things%3A%20HashMap%3A%3Anew()%2C%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20run(%26mut%20self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20needs_action%20%3D%20Vec%3A%3A%3C%26mut%20Box%3CThing%3E%3E%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20modeling%20a%20connection%20on%20one%20of%20the%20listeners...%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20let%20Some(t)%20%3D%20self.things.get_mut(%261usize)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20needs_action.push(t)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20t%20in%20needs_action%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20t.act(self%20as%20%26mut%20ThingSet)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20ThingSet%20for%20Loop%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20register(%26mut%20self%2C%20thing%3A%20Box%3CThing%3E)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.things.insert(self.next%2C%20thing)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.next%20%2B%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20l%20%3D%20Loop%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20p1%20%3D%20Listener%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20p2%20%3D%20Listener%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20l.register(Box%3A%3Anew(p1))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20l.register(Box%3A%3Anew(p2))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20l.run()%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=1). `HashMap::get_mut` returns a unique borrow to 1 value in 1 field of `self`, therefore I cannot pass on `self` to `Thing::act`. I understand why that happens, how that cause a run-time issue, but have no idea how to refactor the data structure to avoid such problems.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait ThingSet {
    fn register(&mut self, thing: Box<Thing>);
}

trait Thing {
    fn act(&mut self, reg: &mut ThingSet);
}

struct Stream;

impl Thing for Stream {
    fn act(&mut self, reg: &mut ThingSet) {}
}

struct Listener;

impl Thing for Listener {
    fn act(&mut self, reg: &mut ThingSet) {
        if true {
            let mut stream = Stream {};
            reg.register(Box::new(stream));
        }
    }
}

struct Loop {
    next: usize,
    things: HashMap<usize, Box<Thing>>,
}

impl Loop {
    fn new() -> Loop {
        Loop { next: 1, things: HashMap::new(), }
    }
    fn run(&mut self) {
        let mut needs_action = Vec::<&mut Box<Thing>>::new();
        {
            // modeling a connection on one of the listeners...
            if let Some(t) = self.things.get_mut(&1usize) {
                needs_action.push(t);
            }
        }
        for t in needs_action {
            t.act(self as &mut ThingSet);
        }
    }
}

impl ThingSet for Loop {
    fn register(&mut self, thing: Box<Thing>) {
        self.things.insert(self.next, thing);
        self.next += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut l = Loop::new();
    let mut p1 = Listener {};
    let mut p2 = Listener {};
    l.register(Box::new(p1));
    l.register(Box::new(p2));
    l.run();
}
```

I could find good tutorials that explained what the borrow checker does and what is not allowed by it. I could not find good tutorials on how to find alternative data structures where I can avoid disallowed references.

Could you give advice how to remodel this specific problem?

Comment: For some reason @Jsor deleted his post, but he had 2 good gists in it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=710aefc653b320c653f289f5e3eee972 and  https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4fecb8d2b584252fd6b6e687db34de5a

Comment: I will accept @breeden's answer before weekend unless someone comes up with a data structure that allows for static borrow checking for this use-case.

Comment: I deleted it because in the unsafe solution it results in use-after-free if you delete an entry in `needs_action` from another listener's `act`. Also, her

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's possible to correct this specific problem, but I feel there might be a more general concern here.  Correct me if I am wrong, but it appears that you run `Loop::run` it will scan through your `ThingSet` then by some condition put a mutable reference to `Thing` on the `needs_action` buffer.  The *general* issue here seems that through different iterations, rustc cannot verify that these different calls will give you a different mutable reference or another mutable reference to the same element. So you can enforce a run-time borrow check using something like a `RefCell` (see Jsor's answer), or you can take ownership from your `ThingSet` and replace what you've taken with something else -- or remove the element from the set all together.

For instance, taking ownership of the element and removing it from the `ThingSet` is illustrated here:

```
impl Loop {
    fn new() -> Loop {
        Loop { next: 1, things: HashMap::new(), }
    }
    fn run(&mut self) {
        let mut needs_action = Vec::<Box<Thing>>::new();

        // modeling a connection on one of the listeners...
        if let Some(t) = self.things.remove(&1usize) {
            needs_action.push(t);
        }

        for t in &mut needs_action {
            t.act(self as &mut ThingSet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an option, but I think instead of a `replace`, better to just use `remove` from the `HashMap` and re-insert it if necessary.

Comment: Ya, i should probably change that.

Comment: OK, so the idea here is that static analysis is not possible with this data structure, therefore `Rc<RefCell<Thing>>` will provide the same safety using runtime checks.

Comment: @wigy It's not so much that static analysis isn't *possible*, so much as Rust's borrow checker can't distinguish between a `Box` (or any other owned pointer) and a flat struct inside a data structure.